# Landscape xib appears as portrait

Tags: ios, rotation

I have a view controller and separate nib files for portrait and landscape. On rotating, I load the respective nib. The methods

```
 shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and willRotateToInterfaceOrientation
```

get called and the nib does change.

The problem:

```
the landscape nib does not appear as landscape, but portrait! The status bar is
correctly rotated and appears on the top:
(Sorry, couldn't paste the image, because my account is new. The screenshot is in   
landscape, with a landscape status bar, but a landscape view shown as portrait.)
```

One would think the problem lies in not setting the orientation as Landscape in IB Simulated metrics for the view, but I've done that and the view appears as landscape in IB. (I don't think it would even be possible to create a rotated button like that if the view was portrait.) Besides these two nibs I have a **mainwindow.xib**, which contains the app delegate, window and view controller objects.

EDIT: I realized that the views are actually rotating, when they should "stay up". It's like there's an extra transformation. When I rotate the phone 90° right, the landscape xib is displayed rotated 90° right. When I rotate the phone another 90° right, the portrait xib is displayed upside down. The status bar is always correctly displayed at the top.

EDIT2: Using

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI * (90) / 180.0));
```

in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation I can rotate the view to landscape left (and to any orientation I want), so I can use that as a workaround. However, I have other projects, where the view rotates automatically and doesn't require the use of CGAffineTransformMakeRotation. It's like something is preventing the automatic rotation here.

Comment: In your landscape xib, did you set the orientation as landscape? If yes, change it to portrait.

Comment: I've set it to landscape. Yes, I've tried setting it to portrait, but it still appears the same way!

Comment: In `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, `return YES;` Also, in your project Targets->Summary, ensure you've set the supported orientations

Comment: Sure. The status bar wouldn't rotate, if the landscape orientation was not supported.

Comment: In your xib, in the `Simulated Metrics` section, check if your controller's view has the status bar option set. If yes, set it to none and the orientation to portrait mode. Then set the frame of the view with width 1024 and height 768(or 748, etc)...

Comment: This made no difference.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this other than manually rotating the UI yourself? I'm running into this exact same problem and I can't find anything on it.

Comment: Wow, has it really been almost two years! Well, there's no solution yet, I've been meaning to return to this, once I have more time...

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the `view` loaded from nib as subView? If Only the status bar is rotating it means your **previous view is hung** while releasing the view and adding the new view.Can you tell how are you adding the view loaded from `xib` to the SuperView.

Make sure you are releasing the **previous view** correctly while loading the other view,put `NSLOG` in dealloc of the views and check whether the view is getting released completely.

Comment: I'm not releasing as I'm using ARC. In the view controller's willRotateToInterfaceOrientation I'm loading the new nib like:        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"landscapetest" bundle:nil];

        UIView *landscapeView = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        self.view = landscapeView;

Answer (score 0):

I had done something similar to this only instead of making an nib file separately I just added two subviews to the main nib as prtraitView  and Landscape View

and switched them as follows

In viewDidAppear method

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{




    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {
        self.portraitVIew.frame=self.view.bounds;
        self.portraitVIew.frame=self.view.frame;
        [self.view addSubview:self.portraitVIew];
    }else{
        self.landscapeView.frame=self.view.frame;
        [self.view addSubview:self.landscapeView];
    }
    self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;




    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChangeNotification:)
     name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
     object:nil];


}
```

and then Implemented deviceOrientationDidChangeNotification as follows

```
- (void)deviceOrientationDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification*)note
{

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

    }else{
        UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
        if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
        {
            self.landscapeView.hidden=NO;
            self.landscapeView.frame=self.view.frame;
            [self.portraitVIew removeFromSuperview];


            [self.view addSubview:self.landscapeView];
        }else {
            self.landscapeView.hidden=YES;
            self.portraitVIew.frame=self.view.frame;
            NSLog(@"Portrait");

            [self.view addSubview:self.portraitVIew];
        }
    }



}
```

It worked very well for me..

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this later. It looks promising. (But still a workaround to a problem that shouldn't need extra work.)