# iPhone - rotation is not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, rotation

I Have implemented

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return YES;
}
```

in all of my controllers. I have the 4 orientation in info.plist and yet my app doesn't want to rotate. The only thing rotating is the top bar. My table view does not rotate...but i can see behind my table view that is it rotating like it should but i can't access it because my original table view (the one that is not rotating) is right over it and takes 95% of the screen.

[image: This is about what it looks like]

Thanks for any support you can give me!

Comment: How are your autoresizing masks set?

Comment: self.menuTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; something like that? where should i put this by the way... in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation ? I put it in it but it didn't seem to do much so I just erased it

Comment: put it in the viewDidLoad and try it with all autoresizing masks. use: `self.menuTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`

Comment: also, check that ALL view controllers are returning YES from `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`

Comment: This is not working either..I can actually see my table view rotate behind my "static" table view. I don't understand why it is not moving . Could it be because I used IB and dragged and dropped a tableView (even though I linked it in my .h)

Comment: Yes, all viewControllers are returning Yes. I didn't set autoresizing mask for all of them though could this be a problem?

Comment: it doesn't have anything to do with IB. when this happens it's usually because of autoresizing masks or because some view controller is returning NO from `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`. also, are you using a tab bar in your app? if you are you need to make sure ALL view controllers in your tab bar return YES from `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, like I said above

Comment: How are your ViewControllers linked to the rootViewController? Do you use Storyboards? Make sure that your ViewController hierarchy is correct, otherwise I suspect that the rotation event chain is broken (ie the rootViewController does not propagate all the events down the chain). Try to DEBUG and put breakpoints in your shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation methods to see if they are called as well.

Comment: @jere I don't use TabBarController but I do use NavigationController
and to Resh32 I think this is what you mean self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController; This is in my app delegate under 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157049/landscape-xib-appears-as-portrait), where the view is not automatically rotating. I don't have a solution, but I have a workaround. In your view controller's willRotateToInterfaceOrientation, rotate the view explicitly:

```
    switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5);
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * -0.5);
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 1);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

I'm calling this a workaround, because I think the view should rotate automatically without an explicit CGAffineTransformMakeRotation call. In my case, I'm instantiating a different view for landscape, which I need to rotate this way. I have other projects, where the separate view is rotating automatically. I don't know why it doesn't do it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In your ViewController.m class, what you might want to do instead is copy and paste my code shown, below the viewDidDisapear method as shown below:

```
/*
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
*/

 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still not working after change, I don't know what might cause this. But I kinda hate it at the moment :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful for you

```
     if(interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft||interfaceOrientation==   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight||interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
   {

           return YES;
   }
```

Comment: where would he put this? he's already returning YES in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation for ALL orientations. this makes no sense